# Mouse Over Text To Display Image On A Fixed Location

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. For some time I have been looking to design my website the same as [Harvard school of design](https://www.gsd.harvard.edu/) but after a lot of search over the internet, I can only find this result [change links with images](http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6V7p5/)

```js
$('#thumbs img').hover(function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});

$('#thumbs2 a').hover(function(){
   $('#largeImage2').attr('src',$(this).attr('href').replace('thumb','large'));
});

$('#thumbs3 a').hover(function(){
   $('#largeImage3').attr('src',this.getAttribute('data-swap'));
});
```

```css
#thumbs ,#thumbs2, #thumbs3 {overflow: hidden; }
#thumbs img, #largeImage, #largeImage2 ,#largeImage3
{ border: 1px solid gray; padding: 4px; background-color: white; cursor: pointer; }
#thumbs img ,#thumbs2 a ,#thumbs3 a{ float: left; margin-right: 6px; }
#panel { position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

//WITH IMAGE LINKS </br><hr></br>
<div id="gallery"> 
    <div id="panel"> 
        <img id="largeImage" src="http://placehold.it/100" /> 
        <div id="description">main image with image links</div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="thumbs"> 
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ee55ee" alt="1st image description" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100/080" alt="2nd image description" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff6" alt="3rd image description" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff3322" alt="4th image description" />
    </div> 
</div> 
</br><hr></br>
    //WITH SIMPLE LIVE LINKS </br></br>
<div id="gallery2"> 
    <div id="panel"> 
        <img id="largeImage2" src="http://placehold.it/100/" /> 
        <div id="description">main image with simple links</div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="thumbs2">
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100/ff3322" >link1</a>
         <a href="http://placehold.it/100/ffc5c5">link1</a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100/eec777">link1</a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100/887744">link1</a>
    </div> 
</div> 
 </br><hr></br>
    //WITH SIMPLE [DISABLED] LINKS </br></br>
<div id="gallery3"> 
    <div id="panel"> 
        <img id="largeImage3" src="http://placehold.it/100/" /> 
        <div id="description">main image with simple links</div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="thumbs3"> 
        <a href="#" data-swap="http://placehold.it/100/ff3322" >link1</a>
         <a href="#" data-swap="http://placehold.it/100/ffc5c5">link1</a>
        <a href="#" data-swap="http://placehold.it/100/eec777">link1</a>
        <a href="#" data-swap="http://placehold.it/100/ff88ee">link1</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

which is not much desired. The result which I got on [this](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/gallery-hover-stay.htm) website is really I am looking forward to the time being. Being new to front-end technologies facing a hard time achieving this goal. I would really appreciate getting help.

Comment: Please elaborate, you want to make it better or something is not working?

Comment: As mentioned above I am trying to mimic the result of this website www.pmob.co.uk/temp/gallery-hover-stay.htm but due to lack of subject knowledge in the front end technology I could not.

Comment: But your example works, do you mean you want to have a working links?

Comment: No, I am trying to build the same thing in http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/gallery-hover-stay.htm and need help in doing so with the source code.
The code which I have mentioned above from jsfiddle  is not working up to my expectation.

Comment: @YovchoKalev or just a simple query is it possible to change the image in a particular place while hovering over different texts.
Just an example of what is happening in https://www.gsd.harvard.edu/ while selecting the categories. How should I replicate that?

Comment: You can change the css on clicking. In your case it is done with $("p").css("left", "25px"); Also, I would strongly advice you to first learn the basics, because the way you approach this problem(especially with jQuery) is going to cause trouble later on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228214/discussion-between-ritesh-mukhopadhyay-and-yovcho-kalev).

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the code referenced in the question, I wonder whether something a bit simpler would suffice.

In particular, there doesn't really seem to be a need for jquery and it's probably useful to get a basic understanding of 'raw' Javascript before taking on a library.

This snippet has very minimal styling deliberately, just to show the basic JS.
**UPDATE** To make the transition to the hovered element smoother all images are loaded to begin with. They are stored in the bigImage element so it will be possible to show them offset and transition them in and out as desired using CSS. This code is just the basic stuff needed to show an image on a hover event.

```js
  

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
    #container div.bigImage {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .bigImage img {
      display: none;
    }

    #container ul {
      list-style: none;
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      margin: 2vw;
    }

    #container ul li {
      width: auto;
    }

    #container ul li a {  
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
 .bigImage img.show {
   display: block;
   }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        
            <ul id="ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Pic 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pic 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pic 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pic 4</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="bigImage">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/300.jpg" class="show">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/300.jpg">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/300.jpg">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/300.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
```

const bigImage = document.querySelector("#container div.bigImage"); //get the bigImage element
const img = bigImage.querySelector("img"); // get the img element within it
const textdiv = bigImage.querySelector("div.text"); //get the div which holds the text

```
    const lis = document.querySelector("#container ul").getElementsByTagName("li"); //get a collection of the li elements inside the ul element
  
  // listen for mouseover event on the li elements
    for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    // on an event this will refer to the element that witnessed that event
      img.src = this.getAttribute("data-src");
      textdiv.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-text");
        }
    );
    }
  
  // initialise the bigImage with the image and text from the first list element  
  bigImage.querySelector("img").src = lis[0].getAttribute("data-src");
  bigImage.querySelector("div").innerHTML = lis[0].getAttribute("data-text");
```

```css
#container div.bigImage {
  display: inline-block;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 2vw;
}

#container ul li {
  width: auto;
}

#container ul li a {  
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
        <ul>
                <li data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/300.jpg" data-text="Picture 1"><a href="#">Pic 1</a></li>
                <li data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/300.jpg" data-text="Picture 2"><a href="#">Pic 2</a></li>
                <li data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/300.jpg" data-text="Picture 3"><a href="#">Pic 3</a></li>
                <li data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/300.jpg" data-text="Picture 4"><a href="#">Pic 4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="bigImage">
      <img src="">
      <div class="text">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot for recreating the whole thing but is it possible to reduce the time of pictures rendered by keeping them overlapped as we can see in https://www.gsd.harvard.edu/

Comment: Ah, so you want them all showing slightly all the time, not like in [link]http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/gallery-hover-stay.htm (which is what I'd taken from the question that you wanted reproduced). Yes, what we need to do is put the images as separate images in-place all the time. I will look at this later.